# magento Autoload.php error

Tags: php, error, magento-1.9.2.0

not connect my homepage ..
what is VES error??
deleting VES easy pdf invoice but not resolve to error
help me please

this is my system.log

```
2016-01-29T03:00:50+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: fieldString  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/community/VES/PdfPro/Model/Communication/Method/Post.php on line 27
2016-01-29T03:02:13+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:02:16+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:02:27+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:03:13+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:03:17+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:04:17+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:04:32+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:04:48+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:04:52+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:06:02+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:08:59+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:09:03+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:09:08+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:09:18+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/ves_pdfpro/notifications.phtml
2016-01-29T03:19:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(VES/Core/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:19:24+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'VES/Core/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/community:/var/www/html/magento/app/code/core:/var/www/html/magento/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2016-01-29T03:41:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

and this is Autoload.php

```
/**
 * Load class source code
 *
 * @param string $class
 */
public function autoload($class)
{
    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
        $this->_arrLoadedClasses[self::$_scope][] = $class;
    }
    if ($this->_isIncludePathDefined) {
        $classFile =  COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class;
    } else {
        $classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
    }
    $classFile.= '.php';
    //echo $classFile;die();
    return include $classFile;
}

/**
 * Register autoload scope
 * This process allow include scope file which can contain classes
 * definition which are used for this scope
 *
 * @param string $code scope code
 */
static public function registerScope($code)
{
    self::$_scope = $code;
    if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        @include COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All errors are related to VES_pdfpro and VES_core.

If you have already cleaned all Cache(s) you may want to restart PHP in order to remove any opcode cache (like APC or op_cache).

Anyway, seems to be a cache or a partial uninstallation issue so please check if you have some templates and/or layout.xml files in the code.

Comment: Please show me how ..! @MauroNigrele

Comment: How to clean cache? System > Cache Management > Flush Cache Storage, How to restart PHP? depends on OS and php version if you don't know how I'm pretty sure that you can contact the server-guy to do it.

Comment: thanx sir ! I owe my resolve to you